# Calculate Word Frequency in Python Dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary formatted like this:

```
dict1 = {
    'one': 'this list is the first one and may be unique',
    'two':'this is the second list and also may be unique',
    'three': 'this is the 4th list and could be unique as well'
}
```

I am trying to get the frequency of the unique words in for each key in the dictionary. I am having trouble counting the unique words and dividing by the total number of words for that key.

I can get the count of the words:

```
count_words = {}
for  k,v in dict1.items():
    count_words[k]=len(v.split())
```

I also can get the count of unique words:

```
for  v in dict1.values():
    inwords = dict()
    split_words = v.split()
    #print(split_words)        
  for single in split_words:
    if single in inwords.keys():
        inwords[single]+=1
    else:
        inwords[single]=1
```

But I cannot seem to get a grasp on how to combine these two and do some math on the individual words counts.

edit: expected output

```
Word: this
count in key 1: 1
count in entire dict: 3
```

Comment: Can you post what your expected output for the example input would be?  And please fix your indentation.

Comment: Ok, edited original post to fix formatting and expected output. Thanks!

Comment: I've provided an answer but I get the impression it will be incorrect. It seems as if you are trying to iterate over all the *keys* in your initial dictionary and test if they are present within all the *values/sentences* thereof or you are checking if a given *key* is present within its associated *value* ? If you clean up your code a bit more e.g. `for word in sentence` rather then `for single in split_words` the answer may become self evident. [Brandon Rhodes](https://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2013/the-naming-of-ducks-where-dynamic-types-meet-sma.html) gives a really nice talk in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

I'm not entirely sure what you are after here but surely the following is what you require

```
data = {"A":"less is more and more is less"}
temp = {key : (len(sentence.split()), len(set(sentence.split())), sentence) for key, sentence in data.items()}
```

Which returns

```
{'A': (7, 4, 'less is more and more is less')}
```

## Explanation

We iterate over the dictionary creating a tuple from the initial data comprising of :

- The total number of words from the count of items in the split sentence
- The total number of unique words from the count of items in the split sentence re-cast as a set. *In Python a set contains only unique elements.*
- The original sentence as is.

## Update

To get a tally of each word in the sentence one can use `groupby` from `itertools`

```
from itertools import groupby
data = {"A":"less is more and more is less"}
temp = {key : {word:len(list(items)) for word, items in groupby(sorted(sentence.split()))} for key, sentence in data.items()}
```

This returns

```
{'A': {'and': 1, 'is': 2, 'less': 2, 'more': 2}}
```

## Explanation

Here we use a common Python idiom for counting each `word` in the provided `sentence`.

### Groupby

`groupby` collects sequential items together. The order of the items is quite important and necessarily one must sort the input or manage the output. The string `ABBB` will be grouped into the following structure

```
{
 "A" : (Gobble the "A"'s in string), 
 "B" : (Gobble the "B"'s in string; following "A")
}
```

Python returns the following

```
>>> {key : list(val) for key, val in groupby("ABBB")}
{'A': ['A'], 'B': ['B', 'B', 'B']}
```

Comparatively the string `BABB` will be grouped into the fragmented structure

```
{
 "B" : (Gobble the "B"'s in string),                 # This key/value pair gets overridden
 "A" : (Gobble the "A"'s in string; following "B"),
 "B" : (Gobble the "B"'s in string; following "A")   # This key/value pair supercedes the prior pair
}
```

Python returns the following

```
>>> {key : list(val) for key, val in groupby("BABB")}
{'B': ['B', 'B'], 'A': ['A']}
```

The latter may be fixed by sorting the data before hand

```
>>> {key : list(val) for key, val in groupby(sorted("BABB"))}
{'A': ['A'], 'B': ['B', 'B', 'B']}
```

or by managing the resulting key/pair tuples returned

```
>>> data ={}
>>> for key, val in groupby("BABB") :
...     data[key] = data.get(key, []) + list(val)
>>> data
{'A': ['A'], 'B': ['B', 'B', 'B']}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, very clever!  I am looking for something a little different. How would you know the count of the words in your example dictionary? e.g. less appeared twice in A and there were 7 words in total.

Comment: Hopefully the above helps you out.